# nhibernate many-to-many with relationship specific properties

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

Is there a way to map a many-to-many relationship with properties on each item in the list specific to the relationship?  The actual case I'm trying to solve is this:

A business can be related to many contacts, and a contact can be related to many businesses.  What I want to do is provide a status for the relationship, like active or deleted and a date the contact was invited (or added) to be a contact for that business.  So say a contact can be active for one business, but pending for another business.

I know I can easily achieve this by just making the relationship an actual entity and mapping the association entity to the collections, but I REALLY hate doing that.  It just feels dirty making something like a relationship an actual entity.  What I'm wondering is if there's a way to map the relationship specific properties to each object.  So, say I have the list of contacts for a business.  Each contact in that list would have a status, but in the mapping it would make that status specific to the business.  I was hoping I could do something like this in what would be the business mapping:

```
<bag name="Contacts" table="BusinessContactAssociations" lazy="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="BusinessID"/>
  <many-to-many class="Contact" column="ContactID">
    <join table="BusinessContactAssociations">
      <key column="ContactID"/>
      <property name="InvitedDate"/>
      <property name="Status"/>
    </join>
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

but of course that doesn't work, because join can't be used within a many-to-many, but it illustrates what I want.

Anyone have any handy nhibernate mapping magic for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know many-to-many is only used for using a typical two column join table. Given that you want to add properties to the relationship you would be better off mapping it as two separate one-to-many relationships with a join class (well it's more than that because it has its own properties but you know what I mean).

**Update**

This isn't nHibernate magic but there's nothing to stop you from using a join class that is private or otherwise hidden and then exposing the properties of the join class from your main classes.

Comment: I ended up doing it the way I really didn't want to by making the association an entity and then using a one-to-many on each side as you had described above.  If I didn't absolutely despise the use of maps, I might have looked into that suggestion, but using strings for property names when I have a well defined set of properties doesn't fly with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<map>` to get ternary associations instead of your `<many-to-many>` mapping.  You can then use `<composite-index>` to get value objects used as the key of the dictionary, if you want more than one property associate with the relationship.  Check out [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/03/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-ltmapgt.aspx) for some example code.